# Symfony2 - Twig - Unable to validate a textarea

Tags: symfony

i have a problem with customize the texarea field in my twig file
The validation of the form dont work if i customize the textarea
When i customize the other fields excepting the textarea and use {{form_rest(form)}} the validation works fine.
if i remove the expression if($form->isvalid()) the persistance works fine.
please help me
here is my code

## The controller:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $produit = new Produit();  
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($produit);  
$formBuilder->add('nom','text',array('required'=>false))
                ->add('prix','text')
                ->add('marque','text')
                ->add('description','textarea');
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
return $this->render('zmsite1Bundle:Produit:add.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView() ));
}

public function createAction()
{  
    $produit = new Produit();       
    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($produit);       
    $formBuilder->add('nom','text')
                ->add('prix','text')
                ->add('marque','text')
                ->add('description','textarea');       
    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();       
    $request = $this->getRequest();       
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){           
        $form->bind($request);           
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();               
            $em->persist($produit);
            $em->flush();               
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('produit_show',array('id' => $produit->getId())));
        }
        return $this->render("zmsite1Bundle:Produit:add.html.twig",array('form'=>$form->createView()));           
    }
}
```

## The file add.html.twig

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} action="{{path('produit_create')}}">
  <table>         
      <tr>
          <td>{{form_label(form.nom,"Nom du produit")}}</td>
          <td>{{form_widget(form.nom)}}</td>
          <td>{{form_errors(form.nom)}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>{{form_label(form.marque,"Marque du produit")}}</td>
          <td>{{form_widget(form.marque)}}</td>
          <td>{{form_errors(form.marque)}}</td>
      </tr>         
      <tr>
          <td>{{form_label(form.prix,"Prix du produit")}}</td>
          <td>{{form_widget(form.prix)}}</td>
          <td>{{form_errors(form.prix)}}</td>
      </tr>      

      <tr>
          <td>{{textarea_label(form.description,"Description du produit")}}</td>
          <td>{{textarea_widget(form.description)}}</td>
          <td>{{textarea_errors(form.description)}}</td>
      </tr>         
  </table>   
<input type="submit" name="Valider" />
```

## Entity produit

```
<?php

namespace zm\site1Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* produit
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="zm\site1Bundle\Entity\produitRepository")
*/
class produit
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="marque", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $marque;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prix", type="decimal")
 */
private $prix;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 * @return produit
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

/**
 * Set marque
 *
 * @param string $marque
 * @return produit
 */
public function setMarque($marque)
{
    $this->marque = $marque;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get marque
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMarque()
{
    return $this->marque;
}

/**
 * Set prix
 *
 * @param float $prix
 * @return produit
 */
public function setPrix($prix)
{
    $this->prix = $prix;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prix
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getPrix()
{
    return $this->prix;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return produit
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form may have csrf protection that is not being rendered adn so it causing the form to not be fully validated.
Either use `{{ form_rest(form) }}` like you have done before (to render the hidden csrf token). Or turn it off in your form ( I'm not at all sure this is possible in an inline form ) otherwise it would be in your form type (from: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html#csrf-protection)...

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'      => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
        'csrf_protection' => true,
        'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        // a unique key to help generate the secret token

    ));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked fine after i added {{ form_rest(form) }} after the textarea field